# AWS - PresignedUrl Upload Error on Browser, Works in Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to upload files to my S3 bucket via PresignedUrl Lambda function. everything works fine via post man. but the Browser based application is failing saying "SignatureDoesNotMatch"

My Lambda function region is ap-southeast-1.

but similar function works fine in ap-south1 (which is same timezone as mine). any idea why is this happening. could this be anything to do with the timezone difference between the server and client.

Please see my code below:

```
 <script>
    $(document).one('submit', '#memberForm', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.get("<FUNCTION URL>", function (data) {

           
            var getUrl = data.uploadURL;
            var fileName = data.fileName;
          
            var theFormFile = $('#fileLogo').get()[0].files[0];
            if (theFormFile != null) {
                console.log(theFormFile);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: getUrl,
                   
                    contentType: 'binary/octet-stream',
                    
                    processData: false,
                    
                    crossDomain: true,
                   
                    data: theFormFile,
                    success: function () {
                      alert('Yeehaaaw');
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                        alert('File NOT uploaded');
                        console.log(arguments);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $("#memberForm").submit();
            }
        });


        return false;
    });

</script>
```

My Code for Url Generation is as below:

```
  'use strict'

const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION || 'ap-southeast-1' })
const s3 = new AWS.S3()

// Main Lambda entry point
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log("execution started")
  var contentType=event["queryStringParameters"]['contentType']
  var path=event["queryStringParameters"]['path']
  const result = await getUploadURL(contentType,path)
  console.log('Result: ', result)
  return result
}

const getContentType=function(contentType){
    switch(contentType) {
    case "png":
      return "image/png"
    case "jpg":
     return "image/jpeg"
    case "pdf":
     return "application/pdf"
    default:
      return "application/json"
  }
}

const getExtension=function(contentType){
    switch(contentType) {
    case "png":
      return "png"
    case "jpg":
     return "jpg"
    case "pdf":
     return "pdf"
    default:
      return `${contentType}`
  }
}


const getUploadURL = async function(contentType,path) {
  console.log(`Content type is ${contentType}`)
  const actionId = parseInt(Math.random()*10000000)
  
  var type=getContentType(contentType);
  var ext= getExtension(contentType);
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.UploadBucket,
    Key:  `${path}/${actionId}.${ext}`,
    ContentType: type,// Update to match whichever content type you need to upload
    ACL: 'public-read', // Enable this setting to make the object publicly readable - only works if the bucket can support public objects,
    Expires: 300
  }
  
  console.log('getUploadURL: ', s3Params)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Get signed URL
    resolve({
      "statusCode": 200,
      "isBase64Encoded": false,
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify({
          "uploadURL": s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params),
          "fileName": `${actionId}.${ext}`
      })
    })
  })
}
```

Also the same works when i try with PostMan.

Comment: Your snippet doesn't show how you generate data.uploadURL, while it's crucial for the answer. In general, the URL should be generated dynamically, on target region. Region is computed into signature, so if you generate pre-signed URLs on different region, it may be the case.

AWS signature is calculated with the time component. If the source and target clocks do not match, then it results in rejections. The timezone should not make the difference, but both source and target should be synchronized with some NTP clock.

Comment: @michail_w thanks for the response. i have updated the question with the code that generate the Url. the code works fine when i try it via postman (even though I'm in Sri Lanka and aws-southeast-1 is singapore. any idea? much appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the signature version:

```
const s3=new AWS.S3({
  signatureVersion:'v4'
});
```